# __asm__ Function Annotation GCC

Tags: assembly, gcc

In the glibc source code there are a number of function prototypes that look like this:

```
extern __typeof (uname) uname __asm__ ("" "__GI_uname") __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")));
```

What does the `__asm__` do in this context? I know that that syntax can be used to define inline assembly, but I assume you can't do that in the middle of a function declaration.

I've searched the GNU GCC docs, but I couldn't find anything about this kind of annotation, just inline assembly that assumes that `__asm__` is the only declaration in the statement.

Comment: Looks like [a label](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html)